# Convert Tensorflow Dataset into 2 arrays containing images and labels

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using TensorFlow 2.0 and I have a batched dataset which contains 968 images and a label (4 element array) for each:

```
dataSetSize = allDataSet.reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1).numpy()
allDataSet = allDataSet.shuffle(dataSetSize)
allDataSet = allDataSet.map(processPath, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
allDataSet = allDataSet.batch(10)
predictions = loadedModel.predict(allDataSet)

onlyImages = # how to create this?
onlyLabels = # how to create this?

# the 'map' function in my dataset returns a batch of images and their corresponding labels
for idx, (imageBatch, labelBatch) in enumerate(allDataSet) :
    # how to concatenate batches together?
    onlyImages = # ?
    onlyLabels = # ?
```

I need to separate this dataset into two numpy arrays. The first array should contain only the 968 images (shape:  (968, 299, 299, 3)) and the second the 968 labels (shape:  (968, 4)). How can I do that?

I checked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420711/how-to-convert-tensorflow-dataset-to-2d-numpy-array) but these examples seem to be using Tensorflow 1.x and consist of a different input type?

Size of dataset and types:

```
dataset size:  968
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((None, 299, 299, 3), (None, 4)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question well, what you need now to do is to concatenate to a `numpy` array as you iterate through your dataset. Note that, during iteration, if you apply `.numpy()` operation, you automatically convert from `tf.tensor` to `np.array`.

Therefore, the following options are available to you:

1. As per the documentation,

   ```
     a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
     b = np.array([[5, 6]])
     np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
   ```

   Output is:

   ```
   array([[1, 2],
          [3, 4],
          [5, 6]])
   ```

   So, in your code, define an initial empty numpy array to which you
   concatenate, on `axis=0`(with imageBatch and labelBatch).
2. Or you could use `np.vstack`(`np.concatenate` uses `np.vstack` under the hood) which provides the same result.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't setting up the empty arrays properly but got it to work like this: `onlyLabels = np.zeros(shape=(0, 299, 299, 3))` and then using `vstack` I was able to get it working.