# TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'> K-Fold on Transfer Learning

Tags: python, keras, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model, k-fold

I'm doing image classification and coded a model using transfer learning. Now I need to perform a K-Fold analysis on it but I get above error. Is this not possible? I found almost nothing online.
I load my data with `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` and then split it in images and labels. The model performs well on its own.

See the code for k-Fold below

```
# Model configuration
batch_size = 32
img_width, img_height, img_num_channels = 32, 32, 3
loss_function = sparse_categorical_crossentropy
no_classes = 5
no_epochs = 10
optimizer = Adam()
verbosity = 1
num_folds = 10

# Define the K-fold Cross Validator
kfold = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, shuffle=True)

# K-fold Cross Validation model evaluation
fold_no = 1
for train, test in kfold.split(inputs, targets):
  
  # Load Model
  base_model = keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(224,224,3)
  )

  # Freeze base_model
  base_model.trainable = False

  #
  inputs = keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
  x = data_augmentation(inputs) #apply data augmentation

  # Preprocessing
  x = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input(x)

  # The base model contains batchnorm layers. We want to keep them in inference mode
  # when we unfreeze the base model for fine-tuning, so we make sure that the
  # base_model is running in inference mode here.
  x = base_model(x, training=False)
  x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)  # Regularize with dropout
  outputs = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax")(x)
  model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

  model.compile(
    loss=loss_function, 
    optimizer=optimizer, 
    metrics=['accuracy'])

  # Generate a print
  print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
  print(f'Training for fold {fold_no} ...')

  hist = model.fit(inputs[train], targets[train],
                   batch_size=batch_size,
                   epochs=no_epochs)
  
  base_model.trainable = True

  model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),  # Low learning rate
    loss=loss_function, 
    metrics=['accuracy'])

  hist_2 = model.fit(inputs[train], targets[train],
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=no_epochs)

  # Generate generalization metrics
  scores = model.evaluate(inputs[test], targets[test], verbose=0)
  print(f'Score for fold {fold_no}: {model.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {model.metrics_names[1]} of {scores[1]*100}%')
  acc_per_fold.append(scores[1] * 100)
  loss_per_fold.append(scores[0])

  # Increase fold number
  fold_no = fold_no + 1
```

This is the complete Error Massage

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _num_samples(x)
    277     try:
--> 278         return len(x)
    279     except TypeError as type_error:

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py in __len__(self)
    220   def __len__(self):
--> 221     raise TypeError('Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not '
    222                     'implement `__len__`. You may be '

TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-6292815144e5> in <module>
      1 # K-fold Cross Validation model evaluation
      2 fold_no = 1
----> 3 for train, test in kfold.split(inputs, targets):
      4 
      5   # Load Model

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
    328             The testing set indices for that split.
    329         """
--> 330         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
    331         n_samples = _num_samples(X)
    332         if self.n_splits > n_samples:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    376 
    377     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 378     check_consistent_length(*result)
    379     return result
    380 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    327     """
    328 
--> 329     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    327     """
    328 
--> 329     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _num_samples(x)
    278         return len(x)
    279     except TypeError as type_error:
--> 280         raise TypeError(message) from type_error
    281 
    282 

TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>
```

Edit:
I run the hole thing again and now it gives a new Error. Maybe I didnt properly run the code loading the data.

As you can see it runs successfully until the first model fit, then it gives the following error.

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/vgg19/vgg19_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
80134624/80134624 [==============================] - 4s 0us/step
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Training for fold 1 ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-6292815144e5> in <module>
     38   print(f'Training for fold {fold_no} ...')
     39 
---> 40   hist = model.fit(inputs[train], targets[train],
     41                    batch_size=batch_size,
     42                    epochs=no_epochs)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.__operators__.getitem_1" (type SlicingOpLambda).

Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 2872, 2873, 2874])

Call arguments received by layer "tf.__operators__.getitem_1" (type SlicingOpLambda):
  • tensor=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
  • slice_spec=array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 2872, 2873, 2874])
  • var=None
```

Code for loading Data and producing numpy arrays.

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  directory ='/gdrive/My Drive/Flies_dt/224x224',
  validation_split=0.4,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(224, 224),
  batch_size=32)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  directory ='/gdrive/My Drive/Flies_dt/224x224',
  validation_split=0.4,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(224, 224),
  batch_size=32)

train_images = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y:x)))
train_labels = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y:y)))

val_images = np.concatenate(list(val_ds.map(lambda x, y:x)))
val_labels = np.concatenate(list(val_ds.map(lambda x, y:y)))

inputs = np.concatenate((train_images, val_images), axis=0)
targets = np.concatenate((train_labels, val_labels), axis=0)
```

Comment: Which line produces the error? This would be easy to determine with the full traceback, always include it.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy I added the error message

Comment: What are inputs and targets? They should be numpy arrays, not Keras/Tensorflow tensors.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy they are both `numpy.ndarray`. I ran the data loading again and now get a new error message. See my edit

Comment: The error indicates they are not numpy arrays, maybe include the code that produces the inputs and targets variable?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I included the code above. I'm so thankful already.

Comment: I don't think that is the right way to transform tf.data.Dataset to numpy, there are multiple previous answers about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535683/extract-data-from-tensorflow-dataset-e-g-to-numpy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420711/how-to-convert-tensorflow-dataset-to-2d-numpy-array